# Usuário com cookies do navegador desativados

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um sistema e utilizo cookies para guardar temporariamente uma informação, porém notei um problema com certo usuário e ao tentar resolver o problema, notei que o mesmo tinha os cookies desabilitados (não me pergunte o porquê).

Eu seto os cookies de maneira convencional pelo php

```
setcookie(...);
```

Então, essas são minhas perguntas:

1. Tem como eu saber se um usuário está com os cookies do navegador desabilitados?
2. Se sim, como devo proceder?

Comment: Não seria o caso de gravar e tentar recuperar um cookie justamente para fazer o diagnóstico e então avisar o usuário de que o site requer a habilitação dos cookies ou até bloquear o acesso ao sistema?

Comment: De certa forma sim, @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que com o PHP não será possível, mas você pode tentar em javascript, algo do tipo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var tmpcookie = new Date();

chkcookie = (tmpcookie.getTime() + '');

document.cookie = "chkcookie=" + chkcookie + "; path=/";

if( document.cookie.indexOf(chkcookie,0) < 0 )
{
    alert('Cookie desabilitado');
}
else
{
    alert('Cookie habilitado');
}

</script>
```

[Referência](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/268647-resolvido%C2%A0como-saber-se-cookie-est%C3%A1-ou-n%C3%A3o-habilitado/)

Comment: É uma boa solução. Nem tinha se passado pela minha cabeça. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada!.Lembre-se, o PHP é server-side. Dificilmente vai ter algo nele pra coisas que são tratadas em client-side.

Comment: Bem lembrado hahaha